# Button control inside bootstrap modal ui is not working

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-modal

How do I get the button control inside the modal to work? I am able to get the modal to open but the button does not work. I am new to angular ui bootstrap. Any suggestion or help would be great!

Here is my component:

```js
export default function (app) {
    app.component('review', {
        templateUrl: 'Content/app/components/review/Review.html',
        controller: ['$uibModal', ReviewController]
    })

    function ReviewController($uibModal) {
        var $ctrl = this;

        $ctrl.ShowModal = function() {
            $uibModal.open({
                templateUrl: 'errorModal',
                backdrop: true,
                controller: ['$uibModalInstance', function($uibModalInstance) {
                    var $ctrl = this;

                    $ctrl.cancel = function () {
                        $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
                    };
                }]
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the HTML of the modal:

```html
<script type="text/ng-template" id="errorModal">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title">Oops!</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        test
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="$ctrl.cancel()">Okay</button>
    </div>
</script>
```

Comment: So `$ctrl.cancel` is never called? did you try to change modal  `var $ctrl = this;` to `var self = this` for example?

Comment: Try declaring `$ctrl.cancel` outside the `ShowModal`, inside your `ReviewController`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Option 1

We need to assign dynamically modal scope, so add property: `controllerAs: '$ctrl',`

a.e.:

```
$ctrl.ShowModal = function() {
    $uibModal.open({
        templateUrl: 'errorModal',
        backdrop: true,
        controllerAs: '$ctrl',
        controller: ['$uibModalInstance', function($uibModalInstance) {
            var $ctrl = this;    
            $ctrl.cancel = function () {
                $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
            };
        }]
    })
}
```

#### Option 2

Try to use modal's `$scope`:

```
//...
controller: ['$scope', '$uibModalInstance', function($scope, $uibModalInstance) {

  $scope.cancel = function () {
       $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
}],
// ...
```

and in HTML:

```
 <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="cancel()">Okay</button>
```

Comment: Awesome this did the job!!